# Quoting my references/source doesn't work in latex with pandoc

Tags: biblatex, pandoc

I use pandoc to compile my text in markdown and latex. I need to quote my source in a latex loop but it doesn't display correctly in the result. I use a .bib file to give the information about my source.

`````
---
link-citations: true
bibliography: [D:\bib.bib]

cite-method: biblatex
header-includes:
  - |
    ````{=latex}
    \usepackage{mdframed}
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \usepackage{pgf}
    \usepackage{verbatim}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \usepackage{environ}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    ````
...
\vfill{{\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{center}
\section*{Text}
    
    test @source

\end{center}
\end{tcolorbox}}}
\vfill
`````

My bib file :

```
@misc{source,
    title = {test},
    url = {test},
}
```

What I don't understand is that it works in markdown, if I do that, it returns my text with [1] as expected

Here is the command I use to compile

> pandoc .\Untitled.md -o Untitled.pdf --from markdown --citeproc
> --bibliography=D:\bib.bib

Thanks for the help

Comment: According to the manual: "... the material between the begin and end tags will be interpreted as raw LaTeX, not as Markdown." You should use latex commands then or -- preferably -- write a filter. *raw_attribute* could also work

Comment: Could you write me according to the code I posted? please I don't think I understood very well

Comment: Means that you can insert  LaTeX in markdown but not the opposite.  Inside any LaTeX environment (or inside a latex command argument), `@source` is just the LaTeX text "@source" the same that `\fbox{*foo*}` is "a box with "foo" with asterriks, not  with *foo* in cursive . If you want a cite in LaTeX, use a Latex command (e.g. `\autocite{souce}`).

Comment: No I already tried the sources with Latex and it shows me "[source]" not clickable and moreover I would like it to show me [1] like in markdown

Comment: You have to make up your mind: Do you want to use `biblatex` (as stated in your document) or do you want to use citeproc (as specified in the command line). In the first case you have to produce a .tex file first (use the standalone option) and compile it then with pdflatex. In the latter case you cannot use latex commands for citations, so you have to come up wit a pandoc solution: write a filter or use an extension